# How to fix drag and drop JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

I created this page and script to drag and drop an object using JavaScript, HTML, CSS. I spotlight object follow mouse to hover over the page item and drop it on the container but my problem is the drag and drop is not working?

Here's the code:

## HTML:

```
<body onload="initPage()">

    <div class="container">
        <span id="spotLight"></span>
        <h1>Drag and Drop Demos</h1>

        <h2>Page Elements</h2>
        <p>
            Drag the elements on the right into the drop area.
        </p>
        <div id="dd-elements" class="clearfix">
            <ul id="drag-elements">
                <li draggable="true">Element One</li>
                <li draggable="true">Element Two</li>
                <li draggable="true">Element Three</li>
                <li draggable="true">Element Four</li>
                <li draggable="true">Element Five</li>
            </ul>

            <div id="drop-target-one">
                Drop Here!
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

## CSS:

```
.container {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1em;
}



#drop-target-one,
#dd-files,
#dd-images {
    border: 5px dashed #D9D9D9;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5em 2em;
    text-align: center;
}

.over {
    background: #F7F7F7;
}

#drag-elements {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
}

#drag-elements li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
    border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
    background: #F7F7F7;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

//spotLight
#spotLight {
 position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 20px;

  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 300px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

#spotLight:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -25px;
  top: -25px;
  right: -25px;
  bottom: -25px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  border-radius: 25px;

  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 300px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}


.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1; }

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: ""; }

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both; }
```

## JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {


    var dropZoneOne = document.querySelector('#drop-target-one');
    var dragElements = document.querySelectorAll('#drag-elements li');
    var elementDragged = null;

    for (var i = 0; i < dragElements.length; i++) {


        dragElements[i].addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) {
            e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
            e.dataTransfer.setData('text', this.innerHTML);
            elementDragged = this;
        });


        dragElements[i].addEventListener('dragend', function(e) {
            elementDragged = null;
        });
    };


    dropZoneOne.addEventListener('dragover', function(e) {
        if (e.preventDefault) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';

        return false;
    });


    dropZoneOne.addEventListener('dragenter', function(e) {
        this.className = "over";
    });

    // Event Listener for when the dragged element leaves the drop zone.
    dropZoneOne.addEventListener('dragleave', function(e) {
        this.className = "";
    });


    dropZoneOne.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
        if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault(); 
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation(); 

        this.className = "";
        this.innerHTML = "Dropped " + e.dataTransfer.getData('text');

        document.querySelector('#drag-elements').removeChild(elementDragged);
        elementDragged = null;

        return false;
    });

};
function initPage() { 
    document.onmousemove = followMe;
}

function followMe(evt) {
    var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((window.event) ? event : null);
    var object = document.getElementById('spotLight');
        object.style.left = evt.clientX - (object.offsetWidth/2) + 'px';
        object.style.top = evt.clientY - (object.offsetHeight/2) + 'px';
        return;
}
```

## Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ca5r2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, a couple of things I found to get the jsFiddle working.

First, the reason the elements aren't draggable has to do with your pseudo element #spotlight:after. It is positioned 'absolute' with top, left, bottom, and right values of -25px. I don't think is doing what you intended. An element with those positions is going to take up the entire screen because it will stretch from 25px to the left of the left border to 25px after the right edge and so on. A temporary solution is to add the css attribute

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Secondly, you have

```
<body onload="initPage()">
```

and

```
function initPage() {
```

Normally this would be fine, but in JSFiddle the javascript window is scoped inside of the page onload handler and so the functions are scoped locally. To get them into the global scope you can do several things, but temporarily I changed the function to be explicitly added to the window scope:

```
window['initPage'] = function() {
```

Also, because we are already scoped inside of the onload handler I removed the

```
window.onload = function() {
```

scoping, including the end braces.

Here is the working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ca5r2/7/)

Comment: love this pointer-events:none; solution applied to text div's... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use html5 ?

```
<head>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true"
ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
```

[source : w3s](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you looking in on using jQuery UI for this. Check out the [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) widgets.

Comment: thanks for note but we need to use native JavaScript because it is faster