# Drag and drop function with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Totally New/Newbie with JavaScript and trying to do a simple drag and drop functionality. For some reason this ins not working at all, added the console.log to check does the website even recognize what is happening and it does not bounce up even there. I have the elements "draggable" and "droppable" on html side.

```
const draggableElements = document.querySelectorAll(".draggable");
const droppableElements = document.querySelectorAll(".droppable");

draggableElements.forEach(elem => {
    elem.addEventListener("dragstart", dragstart);
    elem.addEventListener("drag", drag);
    elem.addEventListener("dragend", dragend);  
});

//droppableElements.forEach(elem => {
//  //elem.addEventListener("dragenter", dragenter);
//  //elem.addEventListener("dragover", dragover);
//  //elem.addEventListener("dragleave", dragleave);
//  //elem.addEventListener("drop", drop);
//});

    // Drag and Drop Functions
    function dragStart(event) {
        console.log("dragging...")
        //event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.color);
    }
    
    function dragOver(event) {
        event.PreventDefault();***
```

Any ideas whats wrong?

Br,
Johnny

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix drag and drop JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985601/how-to-fix-drag-and-drop-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine, but you had typo. Your function is called dragStart() with camelCase, and you call dragstart which does not exist

```js
const draggableElements = document.querySelectorAll(".draggable");
const droppableElements = document.querySelectorAll(".droppable");

draggableElements.forEach(elem => {
    elem.addEventListener("dragstart", dragstart);
});

function dragstart(){
console.log("dragging");
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:red;" class="draggable" draggable="true"></div>
```